# Geo-restore in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, database-restore

In the event of a data center outage and I want to restore a SQL database using Azure's geo-restore capabilities, how recent would this backup be?

Some sources explicitly say that it's a daily backup but others indicate that hour differentials and transaction logs are also backed up indicating that you wouldn't lose too much data, definitely not 24 hours worth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh852669.aspx), the RPO of Geo-Restore is 24 hours for Pre-V12 servers and 1 hour for V12 servers. If you are using V12 your latest backup would be at most 1 hour old. If you are using Pre-V12 servers your latest backup would be at most 24 hours old.